# Intersection Observer with viewport margins in Alpine

Tags: alpine.js, intersection-observer

**Problem**:

Need to execute an action when an element enters the middle third area of the viewport:

[image]

**Constraints**:

I am using [Alpine JS](https://alpinejs.dev/).

According to the [Alpine intersect docs](https://alpinejs.dev/plugins/intersect), I can control the *rootMargin* property of the underlying *IntersectionObserver* using *.margin*, in order to change the limit where the observer will trigger. I'm doing it as follows:

```css
h1 {
margin-top: 95vh;
position: relative;
background-color: blue;
color: white;
z-index: 2;
}

body {
height: 200vh;
}

body::before,
body::after {
content: '';
position: fixed;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 33%;
background-color: grey;
z-index: 1;
}

body::before{
top: 0;
}

body::after{
bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- Alpine Plugins -->
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/@alpinejs/intersect@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
 
<!-- Alpine Core -->
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 x-data="{ message: 'Alpine Is Working' }"
    x-intersect:enter.margin.-33%.0.-33%.0="message = 'ENTERED'"
    x-intersect:leave.margin.-33%.0.-33%.0="message = 'LEFT'"
    x-text="message"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above example, you can see it's not respecting the 33% top/bottom margin with the viewport. I marked those in grey using pseudoelements.

**What should happen**:

In the example above, it should say "Entered" or "Left" when the element scrolls into and out of the white area.

Any idea on what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code wouldn't work for me in the code snippet, but did as soon as I copied it out to a local html file and ran it there.

The iframe is messing with the intersection observer's root.

Your code was useful to me, I hadn't been able to find an example combining the :enter and :leave modifiers.

(I had to write this as an answer rather than a comment due to insufficient points.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).